# WebRTC gradle dependency for android

Tags: android, gradle, webrtc

Are there any pre-built WebRTC sources which I can include in my gradle-based **android** project? All answers so far refer to the [repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.pristine/libjingle) by [pristineio](https://pristine.io/), but it was not updated since 2015. I know that one can build WebRTC code by himself(described [here](https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-build-scripts)) but I want to avoid this if possible.

Comment: I have used this library compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:11139@aar'

Comment: Hi @Akash. Thanks for your answer. I also wanted to use it, but it is was not updated since Dec 2015, and WebRTC source code has significantly changed in the last year.